# XSD Restrictions based on HTTP verbs for REST services

Tags: rest, xsd

I'm writing XSDs for our REST service messages and came across an issue.  Our messages have restrictions that are different based on what HTTP verb is used.

For example, one message that is sent in with a POST or PUT requires one of two fields to be populated, so I'm using the choice Element.  However, this same message returned from a GET request will have BOTH populated which violates the choice restriction.

Is there any sort of work around?  Example message below:

```
<xsd:complexType name="MyMessage">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:group ref="GroupA" />
            <xsd:group ref="GroupB" />
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="SomeString" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy approach would be to record the relevant verb in the message as an element, so your content model would be something like

```
( ((POST|PUT), (GroupA|GroupB))
| (GET, GroupA, GroupB)
| (HEAD|OPTIONS|DELETE|TRACE|CONNECT)
)
```

Alternatively, use different schemas for different verbs, on the principle that the job of a schema is to define a set of messages and your design is that the precise set of messages that's acceptable differs depending on the verb.